# Why do my windows open and close so slowly with a fading effect?

Tags: windows

Sometimes after I boot my machine, Windows starts in a mode where the fade-in/fade-out effect (on window open/close, respectively) is extremely slow.  The fading effect is extremely slow when it happens, so that it requires several seconds for a window to open or close.  Why does this happen?  Can it be turned off?

Comment: Can you elaborate with your question? What OS version do you have? Which windows are slow? What hardware are you using?

Answer (score 5):

If you're running Windows 7...
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Optimize-Windows-7-for-better-performance

It could be an issue with your graphics card, or possibly lackthereof. You can shut off effects by going to Start, Control Panel, Performance Information and Tools, and then Adjust Visual Effects. From there, turn off whatever you think the problem is.
[image]